# Most efficient way to match two fields in hive databases

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, dataset, bigdata

I would like to basically match email fields for two databases in which one table has emails as an email array whereas the other one has a string field, each table has a few billion records. So efficiency is very important.

I've tried making a python script but I think its gonna take a very long time to finish using the script i made which has a time complexity of **O(n^2)**. Any better python scripts are very welcome.

If anyone could propose an approach that would be very helpful.

Comment: you may need to show your table structure with some sample data to get an answer. clear expected results would help further. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would first try and push that logic to hive and try an inner join on the two fields.  You obviously need to convert them to the same string structure, but that can be done in the INNER JOIN statement itself.  Since Hive should distribute the computing across the cluster, it will be as efficient as it can be....
If you post the table structure, I can update with the actual Hive statement that should work.

Comment: exactly. This question is too vague to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I would evaluate Apache Spark for this problem. Even in a single machine environment, Spark can parallelize the request against the database, what can be helpful in this case with billions of records.

Of course, a cluster would be better, but I have very satisfactory performance with Spark in my local machines.

Finally, Spark has support for Python and SQL, I mean, you can choose between these two languages to create your solution. You can start here https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/apache-spark-python, using the pyspark shell.